# How to fetch particular users photos from Instagram

Tags: ios, instagram

I am trying to fetch a particular user's photo using Instagram, lets say one particular sports team, I am unable to proceed further since the API's seem to return images of all users with similar handle? Is there a way around it?

Let me know please.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you're using, but the Instagram API absolutely provides an end-point for an individual user's photos.

Once you've obtained the user's ID you can use the `/users/user-id/media/recent` and `/users/self/feed` endpoints as required. What API calls are you currently using, if not those?